# binding entity interface in cruderepository

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, redis, spring-data

I'm having trouble using entity interface in cruderepository

My project is built with a few modules like:

```
App
 |-- common(interfaces)
 |-- core(services)
 |-- persistence(repositories and entities)
 |-- web(controllers)
 |-- security(UserDetails, filters, etc..)
```

in common I have the following interfaces:

```java
public interface User {
    String getName();
    String getPassword();
    String getEmail();
    UserRole getRole();

    void setPassword(String newPassword);

    void setEnabled(boolean isValidated);

    boolean isEnabled();
}

public interface Team {
    Conference getConference();
    int getWins();
    String getCity();
    String getName();
    String getStadium();
    void addWin();
}

package com.nbaplayoffs.common.repositories;

import com.nbaplayoffs.common.models.Team;

public interface TeamRepository {
    Iterable<Team> findAll();
}

package com.nbaplayoffs.common.repositories;

import com.nbaplayoffs.common.models.User;

import java.util.Optional;

public interface UserRepository {
    Optional<User> findById(String name);

    User save(User user);

    Iterable<User> findAll();

    void delete(User user);
}
```

and in persistence module I have the following implementations:

```java
package com.nbaplayoffs.persistence.entities;

import com.nbaplayoffs.common.enums.Conference;
import com.nbaplayoffs.common.models.Team;
import lombok.*;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisHash;

@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Setter
@RedisHash("Team")
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class NbaTeam implements Team {
    private Conference conference;
    private String division;
    @Id
    private String name;
    private String city;
    private String state;
    private String stadium;
    private int wins;

    public NbaTeam(Conference conference, String division, String name, String city, String state, String stadium) {
        this.conference = conference;
        this.division = division;
        this.name = name;
        this.city = city;
        this.state = state;
        this.stadium = stadium;
    }

    @Override
    public void addWin() {
        wins++;
    }
}




package com.nbaplayoffs.persistence.entities;

import com.nbaplayoffs.common.enums.UserRole;
import com.nbaplayoffs.common.models.User;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisHash;


@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@RedisHash("users")
@Getter
public class NbaUser implements User {
    @Id
    private String name;
    private String password;
    private UserRole role;
    private String email;
    private boolean isEnabled;


    public NbaUser(String name, String email, String password, UserRole role, boolean isEnabled) {
        this.name = name;
        this.password = password;
        this.role = role;
        this.email = email;
        this.isEnabled = isEnabled;
    }

}

package com.nbaplayoffs.persistence.repositories;

import com.nbaplayoffs.common.models.Team;
import com.nbaplayoffs.common.repositories.TeamRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface NbaTeamRepository extends CrudRepository<Team, String>, TeamRepository {
}

package com.nbaplayoffs.persistence.repositories;

import com.nbaplayoffs.common.models.User;
import com.nbaplayoffs.common.repositories.UserRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface NbaUserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, String>, UserRepository {

}
```

and my configurations Files:
under persistence module I have:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableRedisRepositories(basePackages = {"com.derei.nbaplayoffs.persistence.repositories"})
public class PersistanceConfigurations {
    @Bean
    public JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory() {
        return new JedisConnectionFactory();
    }

    @Bean("TeamRedisTemplate")
    public RedisTemplate<NbaUser, NbaTeam> redisTemplate() {
        RedisTemplate<NbaUser, NbaTeam> template = new RedisTemplate<>();
        template.setConnectionFactory(jedisConnectionFactory());
        return template;
    }
}
```

and my AppConfiguration:

```java
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {
        "com.derei.nbaplayoffs.core",
        "com.derei.nbaplayoffs.persistence",
        "com.derei.nbaplayoffs.security"
})
@Import({PersistanceConfigurations.class, SecurityConfigurations.class})
public class AppConfig {
}
```

when spring boots, I'm getting the following log:

```
 Multiple Spring Data modules found, entering strict repository configuration mode!
 Bootstrapping Spring Data repositories in DEFAULT mode.
 Spring Data Redis - Could not safely identify store assignment for repository candidate interface com.nbaplayoffs.persistence.repositories.NbaTeamRepository.
 Spring Data Redis - Could not safely identify store assignment for repository candidate interface com.nbaplayoffs.persistence.repositories.NbaUserBetsRepository.
 Spring Data Redis - Could not safely identify store assignment for repository candidate interface com.nbaplayoffs.persistence.repositories.NbaUserRepository.
 Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 71ms. Found 0 repository interfaces.
 Multiple Spring Data modules found, entering strict repository configuration mode!
 Bootstrapping Spring Data repositories in DEFAULT mode.
 Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 35ms. Found 0 repository interfaces.
```

from my understanding the issue is that I use the interfaces in the crudrepository instead of the entities implementations.

my goal is that I want have dependencies between modules (except common of course)

is there a way to achieve it?

Comment: I don't follow. If entities and repositories are part of the same module, why is it a problem to use concrete implementations for repository generic parameter?

Comment: Could you please give a try to add `spring.data.redis.repositories.enabled = false` to your application properties and let me know if it worked for you?

Comment: @crizzis it won't work because the repository interface in common uses User/Team

Comment: @EstevaoSantiago it didn't work Unfortunately

Comment: Well then, you'll need another layer that translates between Spring-generated repositories and your interface. Not sure why you feel you need an interface for something that is essentially a POJO, though

Comment: @crizzis If I won't use the interfaces I'll have a dependency between modules (for example core will be depend on persistence) and if I move the entities to core, I'll have logic in my common which is a bad practice, and dependency in spring-data as well

Comment: No, the bad practice is that you are adding complexity to something simple that must be coupled anyway ;) ...and eventually you are heading into some storm in between with Spring.

Comment: @x80486 so you suggest I add dependency in persistence module? what if I want to change db? I'll have to change all other modules poms, without the dependency I just write a new module implementing the interfaces from common and tell spring to use that or am I too naive? :), I'm trying to understand the correct structure for a web app and to learn what are the best practices

Comment: I would suggest you to read (and deep dive if you like to later) on Domain Driven Design and Hexagonal architectures; part of it applies to what you are doing to a great extent. Also do not drink too much *kool-aid* about the coupling and creating zillions of interfaces to avoid the unavoidable — there is plenty of that in the Internet. On the other hand, and coming back to your issue, can you post how are you discovering JPA entities and repositories?

Comment: @x80486 thanks for the advice, I added my configurations files

Comment: I don't see anything wrong there; you would have to Git[Hub/Lab]-share your project so we can take a look.

Comment: I found the right solution for me. I tried to avoid it, but didn't see no other way. what I did is instead of using crudrepository, I've implemented the repositories using RedisTemplate, this way I can still use abstract in my modules and the repository implementation uses the concrete types.